# Get the error when execute transaction query in php

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to execute a transaction query in my PHP code that is connected to MySQL. but doesn't work. how can I fix it?

when I execute this query in MySQL without PHP that's work correctly.

```
$query2 = "START TRANSACTION; CALL sp_add_servicesoffer($res,1,2); SELECT @id:=max(Services_Offer.SerOff_ID) FROM Services_Offer; UPDATE Services_Offer SET final_price = (SELECT disc_price from Services_Level where Services_Level.level_code= Services_Offer.level_code)*Services_Offer.service_size WHERE Services_Offer.SerOff_ID BETWEEN @id-5 and @id; COMMIT;";
$result2 = mysqli_query($this->conn,$query2);

if($result2){
    return "ok";
}else{
    return "failed";
}
```

Comment: use http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.begin-transaction.php  and http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.commit.php

Comment: Either split your SQL or use `mysqli_multi_query()`.

Comment: And poll the error message when it fails.http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Comment: u can use `mysqli_multi_query`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem. It's work for me

```
    $query2 = "START TRANSACTION; CALL sp_add_servicesoffer($res,1,2); SELECT @id:=max(Services_Offer.SerOff_ID) FROM Services_Offer; UPDATE Services_Offer SET final_price = (SELECT disc_price from Services_Level where Services_Level.level_code= Services_Offer.level_code)*Services_Offer.service_size WHERE Services_Offer.SerOff_ID BETWEEN @id-5 and @id; COMMIT;";  

    mysqli_begin_transaction($this->conn, MYSQLI_TRANS_START_READ_WRITE);

    $result = mysqli_multi_query($this->conn,$query2);

    mysqli_commit($this->conn);

    if($result){
        return "true";
    }else{
        return "false";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mysqli_multi_query`

```
 $query2 = "START TRANSACTION; CALL sp_add_servicesoffer($res,1,2); SELECT @id:=max(Services_Offer.SerOff_ID) FROM Services_Offer; UPDATE Services_Offer SET final_price = (SELECT disc_price from Services_Level where Services_Level.level_code= Services_Offer.level_code)*Services_Offer.service_size WHERE Services_Offer.SerOff_ID BETWEEN @id-5 and @id; COMMIT;";  

$result2 = mysqli_multi_query($this->conn,$query2);

 do {
    /* store first result set */
    if ($result = mysqli_store_result($this->conn)) {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
            printf("%s\n", $row[0]);
        }
        mysqli_free_result($result);
    }
    /* print divider */
    if (mysqli_more_results($this->conn)) {
        printf("-----------------\n");
    }
} while (mysqli_next_result($this->conn));
```

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't get any result . just run print("---------------\n");